# Spring JPA QuerydslPredicate Snake Case

Tags: spring-boot, querydsl, predicate

I am using spring boot with Query DSL. I have configured my spring boot to use snake case i.e. `spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=SNAKE_CASE`. So my json payload input and output is in snake case like below

```
{
  "first_name": "First",
  "last_name": "Last"  
}
```

I am using `@QuerydslPredicate` for my search functionality. If I enter query params in snake case like below

`(http://localhost:8080/context/resource/?first_name=First)`

it is not parsed by Query DSL Predicate. However, If I provide the params in camel case like below

`(http://localhost:8080/context/resource/?firsName=First)`

it works fine. This is not synonymous with json structure.

How can I achieve snake case in query params so that Query DSL parses it?

This is how my REST end point looks like

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<Output> listUsers(@QuerydslPredicate(root = User.class) Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable) {
            ...
            return new ResponseEntity<>(output, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
```

PN: My Model Object is in camel case like below

**Model Object**

```
public class User {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

I came across a solution on HandlerMethodArgumentResolver, but that is lot of work. There should be a way to automate it than doing all model fields.